# Browser always gets uncompressed script. Pre-compressed with Brotli

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, webpack, brotli, ngx-brotli

Im using brotli to pre-compress my scripts. Here is my scripts
[image]

Nginx config:

```
root /var/www/laravel/public;

server_name mysite.com;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

index index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
}

listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

brotli on;
brotli_static on;
brotli_types *;
```

Here's screenshot from chrome:
[image]

Headers. They are correct i guess
[image]

But still chrome is getting uncompressed file! When i set throttling to "Fast 3G", chrome slooowly downloads 1.6MB uncompressed script. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I needed to comment brotli_static when I installed ssl certificate. Can this be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my antivirus. I'm using ESET NOD32. I disabled http protocol checking, and now i'm getting compressed files in my browser.